# Loading a LongListSelector in MVVM

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, windows-phone-7

I am using MVVM Light for the first time, so bear with me...

I have a LongListSelector on my Main Page, and I am using a RelayCommand to load it with data from a SQLCE database when the page is loaded.

In my MainViewModel, I have a property Workouts:

```
public const string WorkoutsPropertyName = "Workouts";

private PublicGrouping<DateTime, Workout> _workouts;
public PublicGrouping,DateDime, Workout> Workouts
{
    get { return workouts; }
    set
    {
        if (_workouts == value) { return; }
        _workouts = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(WorkoutsPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Then, in the constructor, I create the LoadedCommand:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        context = new XLogDataContext();

        using (context)
        {
            if (context.Workouts.Count() > 0)
            {
                var workoutsByDate = from workout in context.Workouts
                                    group workout by workout.WorkoutDate
                                    into c
                                    orderby c.Key
                                    select c;
                Workouts = workoutsByDate as PublicGrouping<DateTime, Workout>;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When the RelayCommand runs, Workouts always returns null. I know there is data being returned, so I think the problem lies in casting the LINQ query to the PublicGrouping. I've also tried creating the properties as

```
ObservableCollection<PublicGrouping<DateTime, Workout>>
```

but that doesn't work either.

UPDATE:

I changed the RelayCommand to use this line:

```
Workouts = new PublicGrouping<DateTime, Workout>(workoutsByDate);
```

and added this constructor for the PublicGrouping:

```
private readonly IGrouping<TKey, TElement> _internalGrouping;

public PublicGrouping(IOrderedQueryable<IGrouping<DateTime, Workout>> workoutsByDate)
{
    _internalGrouping = (IGrouping<TKey, TElement>) workoutsByDate;
}
```

I still get the InvalidCastException on the _internalGrouping assigment in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public const string WorkoutsPropertyName = "Workouts";

private List<PublicGrouping<DateTime, Workout>> _workouts;
public List<PublicGrouping<DateTime, Workout>> Workouts
{
    get { return _workouts; }
    set
    {
        if (_workouts == value)
        {
            return;
        }



         _workouts = value;

         RaisePropertyChanged(WorkoutsPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                context = new XLogDataContext();

                using (context)
                {
                    if (context.Workouts.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        var workoutsByDate = from workout in context.Workouts
                                            group workout by workout.WorkoutDate
                                            into c
                                            orderby c.Key
                                            select new PublicGrouping<DateTime, Workout>(c);
                        Workouts = workoutsByDate.ToList();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed your cast will fail and using the `as` operator will not throw an `InvalidCastException` in your case so it is being masked.

Create a constructor of your `PublicGrouping` that takes an `IEnumerable` of whatever `worksByDate` contains.

This type of casting (called explicit casting):

```
object o = 2;
string h = (string)o;
```

Throws an `InvalidCastException` if the internal type of `o` cannot be cast to a string.  The `as` operator does not throw this exception and instead returns null.